# Continuous function on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How can I prove this?

> Prove that if $f$ is is continuous on $c$ and $0<f(c)<1$, then there exist $\delta >0$ such that $0<f(x)<1$ for all $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$

Comment: Why do you mean by $f$ is continuous **on** c. Maybe you should use **at** instead. :)

Comment: yes, thats I mean
sorry for bad grammar :)

Comment: The cosmetic edit by @AnotherUser resulted in this six-year old Question being reviewed for lack of context.  I don't think this is a good use of the Close Review queue (the OP has not been around in six years).

Answer (score 1):

First suppose $\epsilon_1=f(c)$ since $f$  is is continous at $c$ then there is $\delta_1 >0$ such that $-f(c)<f(x)-f(c)< f(c)\Rightarrow 0=-f(c)+f(c)<f(x)$ for all   $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$

Again  for $\epsilon_2=1-f(c)>0$ since $f$  is is continous at $c$ then there is $\delta_2 >0$ such that $-(1-f(c))<f(x)-f(c)<1- f(c)\Rightarrow f(x)<1$ or all $x\in(c-\delta_2,c+\delta_2)$

let $\color{red}{\delta=min\{\delta_1, v_2\}}$